# Is there any proper method to do this. how can i do this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

[image]

I am new to react. I am following a video tutorials and get stuck at this point in request.js file.

This error occurred during the build time

```
./src/Row.js
  Line 16:45:  'fetchUrl' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

**Row.js file**

```
 import Axios from 'axios';
    import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
    import axios from './axios';
    
    
    function Row({title}) {
        // useState() is something where you can put your variable(dynamic) like arrays, objects, etc.
        const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]) ; 
        
        // A snippet of code that runs on specific conditions/variable
        useEffect(()=>{
            // if [], run once when the row loads and don't run again.
            // if [movies], it runs everytime when the movie changes. a row has lots of movies
    
            async function fetchData(){
                const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl) //await- wait for the promise to come.
                console.log(request);
                return request;
            }
            
            fetchData();
        },[]);
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>{title}</h2>
    
                {/* container - poster */}
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default Row
```

**axios.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

// base url to make requests to the movie database

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL:"https://api.themoviedb.org/3",
})

export default instance;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Row from './Row';
import requests from './requests';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hey! Let's build the netflix app today</h1>

      <Row title="NETFLIX Originals" fetchUrl={requests.fetchNetflixOriginals}></Row>
      <Row title="Trending Now" fetchUrl={requests.fetchTrending}></Row>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**requests.js**

```
const APIKey = "1cf5ee0bed7e36ed4b2a21b6ac834d55";

const requests = {
    fetchTrending: `/trending/all/week?api_key=${APIKey}&language=en-US`,
    fetchNetflixOriginals:`/discover/tv?api_key=${APIKey}&with_networks=213`,
    fetchTopRated: `/movie/top_rated?api_key=${APIKey}&language=en-US`,
    fetchActionMovies: `/discover/tv?api_key=${APIKey}&with_genres=28`,
    fetchComedyMovies: `/discover/tv?api_key=${APIKey}&with_genres=35`,
    fetchHorrorMovies: `/discover/tv?api_key=${APIKey}&with_genres=27`,
    fetchRomanceMovies: `/discover/tv?api_key=${APIKey}&with_genres=10749`,
    fetchDocumentaries: `/discover/tv?api_key=${APIKey}&with_genres=99`,
}

export default requests;
```

I am using this "fetchUrl" to send the request to App.js file but it says it is undefined.

Comment: The error is pretty descriptive `fetchUrl` is not defined anywhere in the file.

Comment: Thanks..it solved

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `fetchUrl` is being passed via props:

```
function Row({title, fetchUrl}) {
    // useState() is something where you can put your variable(dynamic) like arrays, objects, etc.
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]) ; 
    
    // A snippet of code that runs on specific conditions/variable
    useEffect(()=>{
        // if [], run once when the row loads and don't run again.
        // if [movies], it runs everytime when the movie changes. a row has lots of movies

        async function fetchData(){
            const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl) //await- wait for the promise to come.
            console.log(request);
            return request;
        }
        
        fetchData();
    },[]);
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{title}</h2>

            {/* container - poster */}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Row
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1):

fetchUrl is not defined because you forget to define it in the Row props. It should be:

```
function Row({title, fetchUrl}) { ... }
```